# Streaming Audio with Java

Tags: audio, jakarta-ee, stream, file-transfer

I am building an application which collects speech via microphone as wav files. These recordings need to be streamed to a server and saved (as wav files, I know they are big but they have to be wav). I also need to stream audio (these can be mp3) from the server to the web application to be played for the user. I have no idea how to implement this, but I would like to use a Java EE application because I am familiar with Java and it's easier to maintain than Flex (we are having trouble with old Flex code at work). My concerns are:

1. How do I buffer the transmission so that users hear the whole file without breaks? Transferring the whole file and then playing it is fine, too, but knowing how to do this would be nice.
2. How do I verify transmissions to the server? Can I send in packets and verify/resend per packet?
3. Are there existing APIs for this (please!) or do I have to write this all by hand?

Comment: It is unclear, from your question, how many components are involved in your overall application. You wrote "I also need to stream audio from the server to the web application to be played for the user". That implies that there is a web application *and* a server, and the two are disparate. If this is correct, it'd be useful if you provide information about what currently exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented on your question, it is unclear whether you have already decided upon which components exist in the topology. In particular, it is unclear whether you already have a server process in charge of storing those audio files. Therefore, I will have to make a few assumptions in my answer. Feel free to comment, and I'll try my best to adjust.

1. The only way to *ensure* that an audio file is played (by the end user) without network-induced breaks is to have the end-user (or an application running at the end-user's side, such as some JavaScript code) play the audio stream after it was downloaded in its entirety. Unless you do that, you can only reduce the risk of breaks; you cannot eliminate it. Even the most sophisticated buffering algorithm cannot cope with a network outage 99.99% into buffering the entire stream. As I am not sure whether you have a client-side application involved in this, I can't advise how to *force* the client-side to download the entire file rather than playing it "as it comes"; in the simplest case, you might be able to suffice with using the `Content-Disposition` header: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition
2. The answer to this question, again, depends on how you architect the solution. In general, though, as long as you use standard stream API's (such as Java IO), I wouldn't worry too much about verifying the content for errors. Error-correction is already provided lower in the networking stack (for example, your operating system's networking driver).
3. Apache Commons' File-Upload might be useful - again, depending on your architecture: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/